# Specific regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In python3, I have strings of the format:

```
some_string = 'perhaps here also 19/4986 something else 5/4 somehting else 7/4 and here'
```

Using a regex, I want to get the output:

```
output=['19/4986', '5/4', '7/4']
```

My (unsuccessful) try:

```
m = re.search('[[.]*?([0-9]+/[0-9]+)]*', some_string)
```

and then looping through the results with m.group(0), m.group(1), ...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\d+/\d+` would do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+/\d+', 'perhaps here also 19/4986 something else 5/4 somehting else 7/4 and here')
['19/4986', '5/4', '7/4']
```

`[.]` Means a literally `.`, but there's no `.` in your string.
Also the outer `[]` seems nonsense...

Answer (score 3):

Your regex `[[.]*?([0-9]+/[0-9]+)]*` is not correct as you have used `[` and `]` which is used for character classes and anything you enclose in it is treated as character set.

As I can see you want to find all the pattern having one or more digits followed by slash then again followed by one or more digits, hence you can use this regex and you don't need to loop through all the results instead you can just use `findall` function in `re` module

```
\d+/\d+
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ogLEmF/1)**

Sample Python code,

```
import re

some_string = 'perhaps here also 19/4986 something else 5/4 somehting else 7/4 and here'
output = re.findall(r'\d+/\d+',some_string)
print(output)
```

Prints,

```
['19/4986', '5/4', '7/4']
```

Also, if you wanted to find and iterate over all the matches manually, you can use `finditer` function. Here is a sample code depicting use of `finditer` function in `re` module,

```
import re
some_string = 'perhaps here also 19/4986 something else 5/4 somehting else 7/4 and here'
for m in re.finditer(r'\d+/\d+',some_string):
 print(m.group())
```

Prints,

```
19/4986
5/4
7/4
```

As you can see, the difference between `findall` and `finditer` is, `findall` is a convenient function for grabbing all matches through one line of code as an array of matched strings if there is one capturing group or no capturing group (whole match in that case) and in case there are more than one capturing groups in the regex, then `findall` returns an array of tuples of all matching groups in the regex.

Where as `finditer` returns the match object, which gives you more flexibility to access any of the capturing groups as you want but for that you have to write slightly more code to access any of the information you want. So use the one that is convenient and suits your needs.

Let me know for any queries further.